# How to enforce that subclass of abstract class should define a particular inner class in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class, inner-classes

I have an abstract class from which subclasses will derive. The concrete implementations should include within them an Enum class which holds a set of named constants.

```
from enum import Enum

class AbstractClass:
    def run(self)
        print('the values are:')
        for enum in ClassEnum:
            print(enum.value)
        self.speak()

    def speak(self):
       raise NotImplementedError
    

class ConcreteClassFirst(AbstractClass):
    class ClassEnum(Enum):
        RED = 0
        GREEN = 1
        BLUE = 2

    def speak(self)
        print('the colors are:')
        for enum in ClassEnum:
            print(enum.name)


class ConcreteClassSecond(AbstractClass):
    class ClassEnum(Enum):
        LION = 'scary'
        ELEPHANT = 'big'
        GIRAFFE = 'tall'

    def speak(self)
        print('the animals are:')
        for enum in ClassEnum:
            print(enum.name)
```

this code in fact gives the correct behaviour, however I would like there to be some sort of notation (similar to the `NotImplementedError` on the abstract `speak()` method) That indicates the author of the concrete class should define an inner `Enum` class  called `ClassEnum`. It is needed in fact for the `run()` method.

Some ideas are to have something like

```
class AbstractClass:
    class ClassEnum(Enum):
        pass

    def run(self):
    ...
```

but this won't raise an error if the subclass doesn't define its own version of `ClassEnum`. We could try

```
class AbstractClass:
    class ClassEnum(Enum):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def run(self):
    ...
```

But this predictably raises an error as soon as the `AbstractClass` is defined

I could try

```
class AbstractClass:
    @property
    def ClassEnum(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def run(self):
    ...
```

But here it's not clear that in the subclass ClassEnum should in fact be a class. Perhpas this approach with some documentation could be appropriate..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a clean way in python short of strange metaclasses to enforce definition of class attributes on subclasses.
Given that, I think the next best thing is to instead use instance attributes passed through `super.__init__()`.

```
from enum import Enum

class AbstractClass:
    def __init__(self, behavior_enum):
        """
        :param behavior_enum: enum class with values and names that determine class behavior
        """
        self.behavior_enum = behavior_enum

    def run(self)
        print('the values are:')
        for enum in self.behavior_enum:
            print(enum.value)
        self.speak()

    def speak(self):
       raise NotImplementedError
    

class ConcreteClassFirst(AbstractClass):
    class behavior_enum(Enum):
        RED = 0
        GREEN = 1
        BLUE = 2

    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__(self.behavior_enum)

    def speak(self)
        print('the colors are:')
        for enum in self.behavior_enum:
            print(enum.name)


class ConcreteClassSecond(AbstractClass):
    class behavior_enum(Enum):
        LION = 'scary'
        ELEPHANT = 'big'
        GIRAFFE = 'tall'

    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__(self.behavior_enum)

    def speak(self)
        print('the animals are:')
        for enum in self.behavior_enum:
            print(enum.name)
```